# Combine multiple GitHub pull requests

Tags: github

Is there a way to combine multiple GitHub pull requests so I can see all changes in one place?

The pull requests I want to view will already have been merged into main and closed.  Is there a way to select multiple of these pull requests and combine them to see what files have been changed, in one place.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to view what changed in `main` after all the PRs have been merged you can compare commits in `main` before and after those merges:

`https://github.com/<path>/<to-repo>/compare/<last-commit-sha-in-main-before-merges>...<commit-sha-after-merges>`

ie:
`https://github.com/Hrabal/TemPy/compare/da3b851b7bb1c775744acaa2bdae7aef99510b94...92f8c88ce9b06f585cdc092e419f95ef0c948665`

Comment: Main will have more merged branches than I want to compare with, it will have moved on significantly so I can't use this technique

Comment: @ShamusHarkin in that case another (maybe overkill) approach would be to detach a two new branches from main before the PRs, named for instance `ref_main` and `all_prs`, then merge all the PR's branches into `all_prs`, and make a diff between `ref_main` and `all_prs`

Comment: Good idea, thanks, I might trial it out see how it works for us